# How to save XLSX from within RangetoHTML function to be used as OL attachment

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently able to successfully copy a range of cells with formatting preserved into body of email, however, I would also like to attach XLSX file that mirrors what is displayed in email body. Having trouble passing the file variable between function and email routines.

```
.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Hello " & StaffName & ", <br />  <br /> Reach out if you have any questions/concerns." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & RangetoHTML(rng)

.Attachments.Add ****VARIABLE FROM Function RangetoHTML****

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim myFileName As String

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set tempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With tempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").ClearFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0

    'FOLLOWING THREE LINES SAVE THE FILE THAT NEEDS TO BE PASSED BACK TO OUTMAIL ROUTINE
    myFileName = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "File-" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm-ss") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    .SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
```

I'm able to save the xlsx formatted file that is used as temp file for producing the HTML that gets inserted into body of email. I'm having difficulties passing the absolute file location into the routine where the email attachment is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
```

to

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range) As String
```

and in the function body add:

```
RangetoHTML = tempWB.FullName
```

Comment: I think `RangetoHtMl` returns the HTML, so this is probably not a possibility. The first line is `.HTMLBody = ... & RangetoHTML(rng)` after all.

Comment: Hm.. you may be right, we don't see the whole function. In this case, the function can be updated to return a string array with two elements - the html and the file path.

Comment: Or you could pass the filename `ByRef`.

Comment: @BigBen...could you kindly offer suggestion on how to structure the code using ByRef?

Comment: 'OL MAIL code below...
With OutMail
                .To = SendTo
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "TEST"
                .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Hello... & RangetoHTML(rng)"
                .Attachments.Add
                .Display
            End With

Comment: 'FOLLOWING THREE LINES SAVE THE FILE THAT NEEDS TO BE PASSED BACK TO OUTMAIL ROUTINE
    myFileName = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "RDWR-Quotation-File-" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm-ss") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    .SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
    
    End With

Comment: could you please share example of how to 'pass the filename' using ByRef...thanks!

Comment: `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range, ByRef fileName As String) As String`. The file name variable that you will pass to the function as fileName should be defined somewhere before the call to RangetoHtml. Then RangetoHtml will set it to the correct path. Then `.Attachments.Add [your filename string variable]`